# Shell - Is there any easy way to check if a version format eg x.y.z has three part and each part is an integer?

Tags: bash, shell

example a version must have three part seperated by dots  
0.3.5 and "0.3.5-7.1.0-7" are compliant 
But this 0.89  is not compliant

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you use `grep`?

Comment: Please always show proper samples in code tags in your post, so that it will be easy for us to help you.

Comment: how that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be pattern matching.

```
if [[ $version = +([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]]) ]]; then
```

Comment: what if the last part looks like that "0.3.5-7.1.0-7"

Comment: it stills compliant but with your suggestion is not compliant

Comment: If you're going to change the definition of what is compliant after every answer, we could be here a while. Your question doesn't mention `-` as part of a valid version number.